# Normalize repeating values in Hibernate - Java

Tags: java, hibernate, normalize

I have a String property of an entity, which is often repeated by other entities - which would (in traditional databases) be mapped to its own table.

For example: I could having a clothing entity, with each item of clothing having its own object or row. Each item will have a brand, but this brand (String) could be repeated by many other clothing items. - it should essentially be a manyToOne mapping, though brand is not an entity on its own, its just a String.

How would I do this in hibernate? Or should I rather create an entity for each brand and use ManyToOne?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think that, just in terms of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (most specifically [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)), if you are expecting a column to have repeated values, you should export those values to their own table and have a foreign key column.  That way, if one of those values changed you could change them all at once.

That would allow you to use ManyToOne in Hibernate as well.

However, if that isn't possible, I would recommend using an [Enum](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Java+5+Enums+Persistence+with+Hibernate).

Comment: If you go with enum, you'll have to update your code every time you add a new brand.  Giving a brand it's own entity might make more sense.

Comment: What 'ɲeuroburɳ' says is true, Enums are not a good option. As of now I will be using ManyToOne, though I was hoping for some solution associated with a value-type (embeddable) object embedded in an entity.

Comment: I would agree about the enums.  Normalizing the database itself is a much better option.  I also thought about embedded objects, but it doesn't seem to be very applicable to your problem. [Embedded entites](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Embedded+Entity) are for treating multiple columns as if they were a separate object held by the enclosing entity.  That's not really what you're asking about.