# How to normalize your database in hibernate? (Repeating values don't get saved again and again)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, normalization

imagine I have a table called Photo and a table called Tag.

A Photo can have any amount of tags. Like a picture of the Brandenburg Gate in Berlin has as tags "Berlin", "Gate", ...

Now there is a second photo with the Berlin Reichstag and has also "Berlin" as one of its tags.

At the moment this would now get saved redundantly in my database, this means in my Tag table "Berlin" appears twice and in my join table that has been created by hibernate each tupel directs to its own "Berlin"-Tag.

I don't like this situation, because this means I'm saving redundant data in my database. I would much more like the case that the tag "Berlin" gets only saved **once** in my Tag-table and each Photo that has this tag gets the reference on this one tag object.

So summarized:

***Before (I hope this now gets displayed correctly, when I send this question)***

**PHOTO**

ID | PhotoName
1  | Brandenburg Gate
2  | Reichstag Germany
...|      ...

**TAG**

ID | Tagname
1  | Berlin
2  | Hamster
3  | Berlin
4  | Berlin
5  | Bird
...| ...

**PHOTO_TAG (join table)**

photoID | tagID
1       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 4
...     | ...

***Hopefully afterwards:***

**PHOTO**

ID | PhotoName
1  | Brandenburg Gate
2  | Reichstag Germany
...|      ...

**TAG**

ID | Tagname
1  | Berlin
2  | Hamster
3  | Bird
...| ...

**PHOTO_TAG (join table)**
photoID | tagID
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
...     | ...

As you can see Berlin only needs to get saved once in the Tag table, while there is still no information loss, since the join table references correct on the tupel.

I tried to achieve this with hibernate (I'm not a pro) on a postgresql database. My Photo-Class has an attribute photoTags, which I gave a ManyToMany relationship (I thought that this could mean that every photo can have any amount of tags while every tag can have any amount of photos they're referenced to)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Tag> photoTags;
```

But simply, this didn't work. There is a lot of redundant data in my tag table. 
a
**Now my question: Do you know any sufficient way for me to realize this? Thank for you for every answer and comment** (If you need any further information, like my hibernate.cfg.xml, just tell me).

(This Question here is dealing with a similar problem, but the answer is not satisfying for me: 
[Normalize repeating values in Hibernate - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145069/normalize-repeating-values-in-hibernate-java))

***EDIT: I attach now my hibernate classes:***

**User.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String userID;
private String userName; 
private String userRealName;
private int userPhotoCount;
private Date userPhotoF;
private Date userPhot_1;
private String userLocation;
private String userThumbnailURL;
private int userIsPro;
private int userIsAdmin;
private int userContact;
private int userPhotoS;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Photo> photos;

public User(String userID, String userName, String userRealName, int userPhotoCount,
        Date userPhotoF, Date userPhot_1, String userLocation,
        String userThumbnailURL, int userIsPro, int userIsAdmin,
        int userContact, int userPhotoS, Set<Photo> photos) {
    this.userID = userID;
    this.userName = userName; 
    this.userRealName = userRealName;
    this.userPhotoCount = userPhotoCount;
    this.userPhotoF = userPhotoF;
    this.userPhot_1 = userPhot_1;
    this.userLocation = userLocation;
    this.userThumbnailURL = userThumbnailURL;
    this.userIsPro = userIsPro;
    this.userIsAdmin = userIsAdmin;
    this.userContact = userContact;
    this.userPhotoS = userPhotoS;
    this.photos = photos;

}

// Hibernate requirement
public User() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUserRealName() {
    return userRealName;
}

public void setUserRealName(String userRealName) {
    this.userRealName = userRealName;
}

public int getUserPhotoCount() {
    return userPhotoCount;
}

public void setUserPhotoCount(int userPhotoCount) {
    this.userPhotoCount = userPhotoCount;
}

public Date getUserPhotoF() {
    return userPhotoF;
}

public void setUserPhotoF(Date userPhotoF) {
    this.userPhotoF = userPhotoF;
}

public Date getUserPhot_1() {
    return userPhot_1;
}

public void setUserPhot_1(Date userPhot_1) {
    this.userPhot_1 = userPhot_1;
}

public String getUserLocation() {
    return userLocation;
}

public void setUserLocation(String userLocation) {
    this.userLocation = userLocation;
}

public String getUserThumbnailURL() {
    return userThumbnailURL;
}

public void setUserThumbnailURL(String userThumbnailURL) {
    this.userThumbnailURL = userThumbnailURL;
}

public int getUserIsPro() {
    return userIsPro;
}

public void setUserIsPro(int userIsPro) {
    this.userIsPro = userIsPro;
}

public int getUserIsAdmin() {
    return userIsAdmin;
}

public void setUserIsAdmin(int userIsAdmin) {
    this.userIsAdmin = userIsAdmin;
}

public int getUserContact() {
    return userContact;
}

public void setUserContact(int userContact) {
    this.userContact = userContact;
}

public int getUserPhotoS() {
    return userPhotoS;
}

public void setUserPhotoS(int userPhotoS) {
    this.userPhotoS = userPhotoS;
}

public Set<Photo> getUserPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

public void setUserPhotos(Set<Photo> userPhotos) {
    this.photos = userPhotos;
}

public void addPhoto(Photo photo){
    this.photos.add(photo); 
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

}
```

**Photo.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Photo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private Long photoID;
private String photoTitle;
private String photoUrl;
private int photoAccur;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Tag> photoTags;

private int photoTagsCount;
// ist das korrekt?
private int photoCommentCount;
// date objekte
private Date photoDateP;
private Date photoDateT;
private String photoDescription;
// korrekter Name?
private String photoNotes;
private int photoNot_1;
private String photoMedia;
private String photoMed_1;
private int photoLicense;
private int photoIsFam;
private int photoIsFri;
private int photoIsPri;
// x-Achse
private float photoLongitude;
// y-Achse
private float photoLatitude;

public Photo(Long photoID, String photoTitle, String photoURL,
        int photoAccur, Set<Tag> photoTags, int photoTagsCount,
        int photoCommentCount, Date photoDateP, Date photoDateT,
        String photoDescription, String photoNotesCount, int photoNot_1,
        String photoMedia, String photoMed_1, int photoLicense,
        int photoIsFam, int photoIsFri, int photoIsPri, float photoLongi,
        float photoLatit) {
    this.photoID = photoID;
    this.photoTitle = photoTitle;
    this.photoUrl = photoURL;
    this.photoAccur = photoAccur;
    this.photoTags = photoTags;
    this.photoTagsCount = photoTagsCount;
    this.photoCommentCount = photoCommentCount;
    this.photoDateP = photoDateP;
    this.photoDateT = photoDateT;
    this.photoDescription = photoDescription;
    this.photoNotes = photoNotesCount;
    this.photoNot_1 = photoNot_1;
    this.photoMedia = photoMedia;
    this.photoMed_1 = photoMed_1;
    this.photoLicense = photoLicense;
    this.photoIsFam = photoIsFam;
    this.photoIsFri = photoIsFri;
    this.photoIsPri = photoIsPri;
    this.photoLongitude = photoLongi;
    this.photoLatitude = photoLatit;
}

// hibernate
public Photo() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getPhotoID() {
    return photoID;
}

public void setPhotoID(Long photoID) {
    this.photoID = photoID;
}

public String getPhotoTitle() {
    return photoTitle;
}

public void setPhotoTitle(String photoTitle) {
    this.photoTitle = photoTitle;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public int getPhotoAccur() {
    return photoAccur;
}

public void setPhotoAccur(int photoAccur) {
    this.photoAccur = photoAccur;
}

public Set<Tag> getPhotoTags() {
    return photoTags;
}

public void setPhotoTags(Set<Tag> photoTags) {
    this.photoTags = photoTags;
}

public int getPhotoTagsCount() {
    return photoTagsCount;
}

public void setPhotoTagsCount(int photoTagsCount) {
    this.photoTagsCount = photoTagsCount;
}

public int getPhotoCommentCount() {
    return photoCommentCount;
}

public void setPhotoCommentCount(int photoCommentCount) {
    this.photoCommentCount = photoCommentCount;
}

public Date getPhotoDateP() {
    return photoDateP;
}

public void setPhotoDateP(Date photoDateP) {
    this.photoDateP = photoDateP;
}

public Date getPhotoDateT() {
    return photoDateT;
}

public void setPhotoDateT(Date photoDateT) {
    this.photoDateT = photoDateT;
}

public String getPhotoDescription() {
    return photoDescription;
}

public void setPhotoDescription(String photoDescription) {
    this.photoDescription = photoDescription;
}

public String getPhotoNotesCount() {
    return photoNotes;
}

public void setPhotoNotesCount(String photoNotesCount) {
    this.photoNotes = photoNotesCount;
}

public int getPhotoNot_1() {
    return photoNot_1;
}

public void setPhotoNot_1(int photoNot_1) {
    this.photoNot_1 = photoNot_1;
}

public String getPhotoMedia() {
    return photoMedia;
}

public void setPhotoMedia(String photoMedia) {
    this.photoMedia = photoMedia;
}

public String getPhotoMed_1() {
    return photoMed_1;
}

public void setPhotoMed_1(String photoMed_1) {
    this.photoMed_1 = photoMed_1;
}

public int getPhotoLicense() {
    return photoLicense;
}

public void setPhotoLicense(int photoLicense) {
    this.photoLicense = photoLicense;
}

public int getPhotoIsFam() {
    return photoIsFam;
}

public void setPhotoIsFam(int photoIsFam) {
    this.photoIsFam = photoIsFam;
}

public int getPhotoIsFri() {
    return photoIsFri;
}

public void setPhotoIsFri(int photoIsFri) {
    this.photoIsFri = photoIsFri;
}

public int getPhotoIsPri() {
    return photoIsPri;
}

public void setPhotoIsPri(int photoIsPri) {
    this.photoIsPri = photoIsPri;
}

public float getPhotoLongi() {
    return photoLongitude;
}

public void setPhotoLongi(float photoLongi) {
    this.photoLongitude = photoLongi;
}

public float getPhotoLatit() {
    return photoLatitude;
}

public void setPhotoLatit(float photoLatit) {
    this.photoLatitude = photoLatit;
}
}
```

**Tag.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Tag {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id; 

private String tag;

public Tag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public Tag() {
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

**My Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GIS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

        <mapping class="database.User" />
        <mapping class="database.Photo" />
        <mapping class="database.Tag" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**And now some classes that are dealing my session management with hibernate. They're probably not that important, but just in case. **

**DAO.java**

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics;

/**
 * DAO provides general access methods on the database related to session
 * management (opening and closing)
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public abstract class DAO {

    /**
     * Logs about correct behaviour of the hibernate session management
     */
    public static Statistics stats = statistics();

    /**
     * Ensures that every client gets his correct session
     */
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> sessions = new ThreadLocal<>();

    /**
     * Returns the current hibernate session. Also takes care that there's
     * always an open hibernate transaction when needed.
     * 
     * @return Current hibernate session
     */
    public static Session getSession() {
        Session result = sessions.get();
        if (result == null) {
            result = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sessions.set(result);
            result.beginTransaction();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the current hibernate session, if there is one.
     */
    public static void closeSession() {
        Session sess = sessions.get();
        if (sess == null || !sess.isOpen())
            return;
        sessions.remove();

        try {
            Throwable error = null;
            try {
                if (sess.getTransaction().isActive() == true) {
                    sess.getTransaction().commit();
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                sess.getTransaction().rollback();
                error = e;
            } finally {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Sessions geöffnet bisher: "
                            + stats.getSessionOpenCount());
                    sess.close();
                    System.out.println("Sessions geschlossen bisher: "
                            + stats.getSessionCloseCount());
                } catch (Throwable th) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        error.addSuppressed(th);
                    } else {
                        throw th;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Statistics statistics() {
        Statistics stats = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        return stats;
    }

}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class UserDAO extends DAO {

    public void createUser(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("user must be not null");
        }

        Session session = getSession();

        // speichern des test in der datenbank
        session.save(user);

        closeSession();

    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User doesnt exist");
        }
        Session session = getSession();

        // updaten des Users in der datenbank
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);

        closeSession();
    }

    public User getUser(Long userID) {
        Session session = getSession();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> oneUser = session.createQuery(
                "FROM User WHERE id = " + userID).list();

        closeSession();

        return oneUser.get(0);
    }

    public User getUserByUserID(String userID) {
        Session session = getSession();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> oneUser = session.createQuery(
                "FROM User WHERE userID = '" + userID + "'").list();

        closeSession();
        if (oneUser.size() > 0) {
            return oneUser.get(0);
        } else {
            // user existiert nicht
            return null;
        }

    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Session session = getSession();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> allUsers = session.createQuery("FROM users").list();

        closeSession();

        return allUsers;
    }

}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * HibernateUtil manages the access to the sessionFactory, which ensures that
 * there's always an open database session
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateUtil {

    final private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // create the sessionfactory from standardconfig file
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // log the exception
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current SessionFactory
     * 
     * @return Current SessionFactory
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**HibernateListener.java**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;


/**
 * The HibernateListener takes care that hibernate for the database connection
 * management gets initialised on the server start.
 */
public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {

    /**
     * Calls the static initializer of the HibernateUtil class
     */
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); // Just call the static initializer
                                            // of that class
    }

    /**
     * Frees all ressources when the server is being restarted
     */
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close(); // Free all resources
    }
}
```

Comment: Post all your hibernate classes. ManyToMany should work as you are expecting.... I don't know why you are getting Tags duplicated... Have you overridden equals and hashCode properly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I attached all hibernate classes and my hibernate.cfg.xml. I have not overridden equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are expecting it to work is how it's supposed to work.

I don't see anything wrong in the Hibernate model classes you have posted, so I can only assume that you are setting new Tag instances to the photo instead of loading them and setting them.

When you do that hibernate doesn't know if these objects are equal or not because they don't have an ID set (you just create them remember?).

Load the Tag objects and assign them to photos or if you are hell bent on adding new instances remove cascade all option and override the equals method to consider other details than the ID if the id is not set (null).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You got me on the right way, because I was really creating new Tag instances all the time thinking that hibernate would actually filter it out for me. 

I am now for every tag checking if it already exists in the Tag table and if it does so, I'll retrieve it and assign it to the photo. 

This worked quite good for the first 200 photos and then I got a "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" exception on a Tag object. (next comment, no more space ...)

Comment: I don't really know why this happens. Maybe(?!) because the tag object SOMEHOW gets into trouble because it is now assigned to more Photos than before (although I don't really understand why this has to happen at photo ~200). Any Idea? My brain is struggeling :-)

Anyway, I solved the exception for the moment with using session.merge() instead of session.saveOrUpdate() in the UserDAO. Do you think I might get into another trouble with using merge()? 

Sorry for the long comment, thanks for your great answer!

Comment: Nope nothing wrong with merge method. I'm afraid I'm not good enough to tell you why that error may have occurred without looking at the entire code and debugging :-)